# Find character ' \ ' by function find()

Tags: c++, string, find

I want to find character '\' in string by

> `find()`

but it's not work

> ```
> string a;
> int c=a.find("\");
> ```

Can you fix it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the search character / search string "\" in your function call:

```
int c = a.find('\\');
```

should work.